# Pulling Data from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table in HTML:

```
<tr class="inner2-top">
<td class="name1"> Hello </td>
</tr>
```

How would I get the name1 in a javascript variable function like this?

```
function grabData() {
var name = // todo

}
```

Comment: Bruvoo! you missing some brainstorming session which you need to do : i.e. What event? when do you want to collect the data? rest solution will be based on that. you have class so it its on click travese dom to get that info. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You want the data that's inside of the `td`?

```
function grabData(className) {
    return document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0].innerText;
}

console.log(grabData("name1"));
```

I suggest using `id` attributes instead of `class` attributes if you're going to use this method, though. `id`s are unique whereas `class`es are not, which will explain why you get unexpected results if you have more than one element with the `class` "name1" etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = $(".name1").text();
```

Try the above

Comment: That works, but it's actually grabbing all three of the names in my table rather than the one I've selected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can get that text using class selector

```
var getName=$('.name1').html();
alert(getName);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/AKTf4/)